# Cannot read property 'click' of undefined - Cypress

Tags: cypress

I basically want to run the below function but it gives me an error. Please give me a hand if you can. Thank you

```
 

cy.get('[data-auction-type-text=Regular]').should('be.visible')
            .each(($el,index) => {
                if(index==0){
                    $el.then.click()
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `click()` on the $el

```js
cy.get('[data-auction-type-text=Regular]').should('be.visible')
  .each(($el,index) => {
     if (index === 0) {
       $el.click()
     }
```

or without `.each()`

```js
cy.get('[data-auction-type-text=Regular]').should('be.visible')
  .eq(0)          // equivalent to if(index==0)
  .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$el.then.click()` you have to use -

```
cy.wrap($ele).click()
```

`$ele` is a jquery wrapped element. In order to use cypress commands, we have to use wrap.

Comment: Why do you have to use wrap?

Comment: actually you answer helped a lot. Thank you. But while I rated your answer it showed -1. I am sorry for that

Comment: @Luna It's someone else who downvoted the answer, not you. And you can only upvote an answer when you have a rep of 15 points and above. But if you are satisfied with this answer, you mark it as the answer.